# Generate a total price from the items in state and output it in JSX (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, javascript-objects

I have data in an array of objects:

```
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    category: "tables",
    name: "N/A",
    price: 0,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    category: "tables",
    name: "Table 1",
    price: 220,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    category: "tables",
    name: "Table 2",
    price: 420,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    category: "tables",
    name: "Table 3",
    price: 515,
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    category: "tables",
    name: "Table 4",
    price: 495,
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    category: "tables",
    name: "Table 5",
    price: 210,
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    category: "chairs",
    name: "N/A",
    price: 0,
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    category: "chairs",
    name: "Chair 1",
    price: 75,
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    category: "chairs",
    name: "Chair 2",
    price: 150,
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    category: "desks",
    name: "Desk 1",
    price: 75,
  },
  {
    id: 11,
    category: "desks",
    name: "Desk 2",
    price: 130,
  },
  {
    id: 12,
    category: "desks",
    name: "Desk 3",
    price: 215,
  },
  {
    id: 13,
    category: "desks",
    name: "Desk 4",
    price: 275,
  },
  {
    id: 14,
    category: "lighting",
    name: "Lighting 1",
    price: 105,
  },
  {
    id: 15,
    category: "lighting",
    name: "Lighting 2",
    price: 150,
  },
];

export default data;
```

I have a reducer which updates the state depending on which items the user selects on the page (via radios, checkboxes and quantity inputs). Here's what the initial state looks like. The nested keys correspond to the ids in `data` and the values are the quantities, e.g. there are two desks currently selected (with ids 10 and 12, and 1 quantity of each). Lighting has x2 of id 14 and id 15 has its quantity set to zero as this is output on the page as the initial value in a quantity input.

```
  const [reducerState, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {
    tables: {
      1: 1,
    },
    chairs: {
      7: 1,
    },
    desks: {
      10: 1,
      12: 1,
    },
    lighting: {
      14: 2,
      15: 0,
    },
  });
```

What I need to do is calculate a total price based on the ids and quantities in state. In this example it should be £500. How can I generate this and output it on the page in the JSX?

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working example:

You have to create a reducer function which goes through every selected option, finds that id in the data and then adds the count*price to the sum so far.

https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-sammet-b5m3y9?file=/src/App.js

Comment: That's so much more complicated than I expected! I'm starting to wonder if I've made this more difficult than it needs to be by organising my state in such a way.

Comment: State nesting into tables, chairs, lighting, etc. made this a bit more complicated since we had to flatten the object first. I would probably remove that piece of information unless you really need it.
That relationship is already established through the data object.

You would then only need a reducer or a forEach loop to just walk through the state and do a sum of all selected prices

Comment: Do you mind showing me what that would look like if I were to remove that nesting?

Comment: This would be the adjusted code, I also switched the reducer to a forEach loop:

[CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-https-cdc1ck?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what your reducer switch does, but the logic to check and eventually add the price could be:

```
     const totalPriceForType=(data,initState) =>            data.map(item=>
initState.map(id=>
item.id===id && item.price+=item.price))
```